# R add new line to expression vector

Tags: r

I have a boxplot with four groups and I want to add a name to each group that consists **of two lines** and **includes subscripts**. Therefore I tried using `bquote()`:

```
#sample data
groups = matrix(1:40,ncol=4)

#create group names
names = as.expression(sapply(1:4, function(x){
  letter = LETTERS[x]
  name = bquote(atop(.(letter),num[.(x)] == .(x)))
  return(name)
}))

boxplot(groups, names = names)
```

Which gives me the following result:
[image]

I'm almost pleased with the result. However, `atop()` has some weird spacing so that the top line (with letters A-D) lies on top of the outer boundary. I couldn't find any solution working for me to solve this problem.

I also tried the following:

```
#Alternative Approach (not working)
names = parse(text=paste(LETTERS[1:4],"\n","num[", 1:4, "]", sep=""))
```

In this case, the addition of "\n" (new line) simply breaks the `names` variable from length 4 into length 8.

I have absolutely no idea how to solve this seemingly simple problem. Help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this:

```r
#sample data
groups = matrix(1:40,ncol=4)

#create group names
names = as.expression(sapply(1:4, function(x){
  letter = LETTERS[x]
  name = bquote(atop(.(letter),num[.(x)] == .(x)))
  return(name)
}))

boxplot(groups, names = LETTERS[1:4])
mtext(parse(text=paste("num[", 1:4, "]", sep="")), side=1, at=1:4, line=2)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-11-24 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to translate this plot to `ggplot2`:

```r
library(tidyverse)

groups = matrix(1:40,ncol=4)

#create group names
names = as.expression(sapply(1:4, function(x){
  letter = LETTERS[x]
  name = bquote(atop(.(letter),num[.(x)] == .(x)))
  return(name)
}))


as.data.frame.matrix(groups) |>
  `colnames<-`(LETTERS[1:4]) |>
  pivot_longer(everything()) |>
  ggplot(aes(name, value))+
  geom_boxplot(fill = "grey")+
  scale_x_discrete(labels = names)+
  labs(x = "", y = "")+
  theme_bw()+
  theme(panel.grid = element_blank())
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The distance of the tick labels from the X axis is controlled by the middle number of the `mgp` graphical parameter -- 2.5 in the example below.  See `?par` for more information.    Adjust the 2.5 to your taste.  Note that `names` could be compactly calculated by constructing it as a character vector and then parsing it

```
fmt <- 'atop("%s", num[%dL] == %dL)'
names <- parse(text = sprintf(fmt, head(LETTERS, 4), 1:4, 1:4))
```

however, below the code is the same as in the question except for the two added `par` lines.  The last `par` line is only to reset the graphical parameters and provides some defensiveness in case there are further plots but at the expense of giving this up it could be omitted if there are no further plots.

```
groups = matrix(1:40,ncol=4)

#create group names
names = as.expression(sapply(1:4, function(x){
  letter = LETTERS[x]
  name = bquote(atop(.(letter),num[.(x)] == .(x)))
  return(name)
}))

opar <- par(mgp = c(3, 2.5, 0))
boxplot(groups, names = names)
par(opar)
```

[image: screenshot]